# How to find the lowest sum of numbers for corresponding elements equal to given value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've the following input

```
c1, c2
1,  41
2,  76
3,  109
4,  133
5,  149
6,  157
7,  174
8,  185
9,  200
10,  211
11,  223
12,  232
13,  245
14,  258
```

What I need to do is to find the lowest sum of `c2` for which sum of corresponding values from `c1` is equal to `24`. E.g. for `10` and `14` sum is `469`. I suppose that this is something simple for an experienced excel user which I'm definitely not. Values can be used more than once so `3*8` works well as well as `3*7+3`.

Comment: Can values be used more than once? E.g. 14 `1`'s total `574`.

Comment: Thanks for a good question @ImaginaryHuman072889, yes they can.

Comment: I suggest adding the VBA tag then. This definitely sounds too complicated to do with formulas alone. Probably could be done, but would require a bunch of helper cells.

Comment: 3*7+3 is not a sum. A sum is the addition of numbers. Make up your mind.

Comment: Thanks. Hoped that people here know mathematical operations. Too optimistic as usual.

Comment: I agree, at least for a general solution, but for these particular numbers it looks as though there is no benefit in taking more than two at a time, which would make it easier. As a first try it looks as if you might look for a minimum sum of c2/c1 but I've no idea if this is mathematically sound (this leads to 2*12 -> 464).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like quite of a hard question. I think it's actually a fundamental issue of computer science you are trying to tackle. You can have a look on the Knapsack problem on wiki for further theoretical discussion, so I don't believe you are going to get both simple and totally correct answers. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Anyhow, if the values of c1 are simple enough, lets say integers (no fractions or real numbers) you can use dynamic programming technique, meaning solving many sub-problems similar to your question but for sum lower then 24 and for less rows then what you have. Combining these together can help you solve the harder question.

Lets define SubProb(N,i) = the solution for sum N in c1, using only 1...i rows.
If so, SubProb(N,i) = min(taking an instance from the i-th row, not taking any instance on the i-th row). Theses are all the options available. 
in that case it's the minimum of two simpler problems:

- Taking an instance from the i-th row meaning you now need to take only N-i more from c1 and can still use only 1...i rows, so it is the SubProb(N-i,i), + c2 value of i.
- Not taking any instance on the i-th row meaning you can just take the result of SubProb(N,i-1).

Now we calculate all these problem up to SubProb(24,14) in a clever order and get the answer we wish. The simplest way of doing this is to put them in a table with axis N,i so it is easy to pull values without many recursive overhead.

I implemented this for you in an excel file, here is the link. If you wish to do it on bigger i or N just extend the table by dragging the last row and column of it with the extension tool (the tiny black cross in the corner of the cell). It can be found on this link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K0iROL9mb2NURM7Q0oUKzAFH4jNxNGtk

Oh, and the answer is 464.

Comment: Great answer, explanation, and excel. Is it a condition that c2 is sorted, i.e. for a given c1, the c2 value is higher than the one for the preceding c1 ?

Comment: @Peter k. - not at all. I think the excel will get a bit wild if you put fractions to c1, it's probably going to mess the address function, getting two numbers i, j and returning a reference to the cell in row i col j. Also if a sum is unreachable (lets say 1 is not in c1) a default value of 9999999 is gonna appear instead. For too big tables and c2 values it might be too small. I have tested some reasonable examples and I think it works well also for more general cases. If it's doing some problems to you please let me know.

Comment: @MAya Hey, no I have no *problems* with the Excel. I was just intrigued by the question and the solution in Excel. While going through the Excel, I thought I did understand how it worked, but apparently I didn't ..  (probably not smart enough ;))